# Como puedo enviar cookies entre subdominios, para manejar la autenticacion

Tags: javascript, java, autenticación, jwt, cookies

estoy enfrentando algunos problemas al momento de realizar la autenticación usando cookies, las cuales deben enviarse entre subdominios  por ejemplo la persona se autentica en el dominio app.ejemplo.co en el cual está la aplicación  y consume un servicio en services.ejemplo.co, el sevices.ejemplo.co crea la cookie y la envia en la cabecera, especificando en la cookie la etiqueta dominio=.ejemplo.co que de acuerdo a la documentación RFC6265 es la forma correcta de decir al navegador que para todos los subdominios de ejemplo.co debe almacenar y enviar la cookie en cada petición, obviamente este no es el resultado que se obtiene.

**Nota** : Estamos tratando de manejar la autenticación de la forma en como lo hace google, en el cual nos autenticamos en accounts.google.com y cualquiera de las aplicaciones pueden enviar la información de autenticación (email.google.com,hangoust.google.com, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

cross-domain cookies podría ser una opción:

```
// La cookie expira en un año (12)
const expirationDate = new Date();
expirationDate.setMonth(expirationDate.getMonth() + 12);

// Crea la cookie con el dominio .ejemplo.com
// Todos los subdominios de .ejemplo.com tendrá acceso a la cookie
// y podrán hacer la validación de la sesión correspondiente.
document.cookie = `session=${sessionId};domain=.ejemplo.com;path=/;expires=${expirationDate}`;
```

Déjame saber si fue de ayuda mi respuesta.